# Как задать двузначный формат числа для переменной в Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Вот пример кода:

```
for x in 1..79
puts "reg#{x}"
 for y in 1..20
 puts "reg#{x}-#{y}"
 end
x = x + 1
end
```

Переменные x и y в нём - числа, поэтому результат выглядит так:
reg1-1
...
reg79-1
...

Я бы хотел получить результат в виде "reg01-01 ... reg79-01..." и т. д.
Вопрос: можно ли сделать это, например, заранее задав тип переменной (если такой тип существует)? Или нумерация вида 01, 02, 03 - это всегда будет string и арифметических действий с ней не проделать?
Вариант с костылём в виде условия, добавляющего 0 куда надо, хочу обдумывать в последнюю очередь.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых

> x = x + 1

эта строчка не нужна, `x` и так проходит по `1..79` с интервалом в единицу.

Во-вторых такой код принято писать так:

```
(1..79).each do |x|
  puts "reg#{x}"
  (1..20).each do |y|
    puts "reg#{x}-#{y}"
  end
end
```

Ну а собственно вывести число с нулями спереди можно так: `x.to_s.rjust(2, '0')` где 2 -- длина числа в символах.

Т.е.

```
(1..79).each do |x|
  x_str = x.to_s.rjust(2, '0')
  puts "reg#{x_str}"
  (1..20).each do |y|
    y_str = y.to_s.rjust(2, '0')
    puts "reg#{x_str}-#{y_str}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[]
(1..79).each do |v|
  (1..20).each do |v2|
   a<<'reg'+sprintf('%02d', v)+'-'+sprintf('%02d', v2)
  end
end

puts a
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5mR02LV7qs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Класс `String` имеет метод `%`, реализующий классический `printf`:

```
1.upto 79 do |x|
  puts "reg%02d" % x
  1.upto 20 do |y|
    puts "reg%02d-%02d" % [x, y]
  end
end
```